# How do i read lines in txt and use them in a method for ruby, exactly as the text is?

Tags: ruby, class, text, methods

```
class Test

  def self.take_test( question, options, answer )
    puts question
    options.each_with_index { |option, idx| puts "#{ idx + 1 }: #{ option}" }
    print "Answer: "
    reply = gets.to_i
    if answer == reply
      puts "Correct!"
    else
      puts "Wrong. The answer is: " + answer.to_s
    end
  end
end

file = File.open("Matematik.txt", "r")
```

This is what i tried to do:

```
  IO.foreach("Matematik.txt") { |line| Test.take_test(line) }
```

This is how the questions are set up in the file:

'What is 2+2?', [ '2', '3', '4', '5', ], 4

'What is 3+3?', [ '3', '6', '9', ], 6

I get the error: take_test wrong number of arguments given (given 1, expected 3) (ArgumentError)

It seems like it reads the line like 1 argument. Is there a way to read the lines exactly as i stands, and input it like this?:

```
#Test.take_test('What is 2+2?', [ '2', '3', '4', '5', ], 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes, with `eval("Test.take_test(#{line})")`. However, `eval` is evil, and to be avoided if at all possible.

It would be much easier if you changed your file format so you can deconstruct it easily. (It is not *impossible* with your format, it's just you have a lot of unnecessary work, when compared to a simpler format.) For example, given lines formatted like [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

```
"What is 2+2?",2,3,4,5,4
```

it is very easy to do the following:

```
require 'csv'

Question = Struct.new(:text, :options, :answer)

questions = CSV.read("Mathematik.csv").map { |text, *options, answer|
  Question.new(text, options, answer.to_i)
}

questions[0].text
# => "What is 3+3?"

questions[0].options
# => ["2", "3", "4", "5"]

questions[0].answer
# => 4
```

Comment: Thanks! What is wrong with using eval? It has fixed my problem so far.

Comment: The primary concern is security, unless you know exactly where the data is coming from, since `eval` allows for execution of arbitrary code. For example, imagine someone sneaks this line into your program: ``[`cat /etc/passwd`,["Haha", "What", "a", "sucker!"], 0]``; when it comes the time to display the question, your user will be shown the password file. Even if you know where the data is coming from, `eval` kills Ruby's method cache, making your code slower. But primarily security: if one trains oneself never to use `eval`, one can't be tempted to accidentally use it insecurely.

Comment: Obviously, "`eval` is evil" is a pithy oversimplification, but read [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311507/why-are-eval-like-features-considered-evil-in-contrast-to-other-possibly-harmfu) for well-reasoned discussion. tl;dr: `eval` should never be your first choice, only use it when you must, after careful deliberation.